# How should I load package.json for a CLI app installed globally?

Tags: javascript, npm, command-line-interface, npm-install, package.json

I created a cli application which reads its version number from package.json with this bit of code

```
const packageJson = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('./package.json'), 'utf8'))
```

This works fine if I run the app with `yarn start` or a similar command while development
But after the package is installed with `npm install --global app-name` the user should use the declare executable from any path on the system. So if I want to run it say in `/Users/myUser/Desktop` I get an error like this

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/myUser/Desktop/package.json'
```

So what's a good protocol of loading this package.json within my CLI or is there a better way for approaching this?

---

Later edit:
For clarity, my package json contains this

```json
{
...
"bin": {
    "clip": "./bin/clip.js"
  },
...
}
```

so what I mean by my problem, is when I am running the executable "clip" from a different path, after I used `npm publish`

After some research I tried this code (use the path.dirname function):

```
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename)
export const packageJsonLocation = path.join(__dirname, './../package.json')
const packageJson = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(packageJsonLocation, 'utf8'))
```

and this (just importing the file as json using node's standard import keyword)

```
import * as packageJson from './../package.json' assert { type: 'json' }
```

in both cases I get the same result, the executable generated and it tries to read package.json from the current directory. Specifically if I try to console.log() the path I get my current path where I am executing the global executable (clip in my case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `__dirname` because it always refers to the path of the file that contains this variable, whereas `./` gives you the working directory, such as `process.cwd()`.

```js
const packageJson = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(
  path.join(__dirname, 'package.json'), 'utf8')
)
```

If you're using ES Modules, do also to get `__dirname`

```js
import { dirname } from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

const __dirname = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));

const packageJson = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(
  path.join(__dirname, 'package.json'), 'utf8')
)
```

**Edit:**

You installed the package globally with a bin, but the bin you're calling with a CLI is a symlink which is inside the path `<npm_glob_path>/node_modules/bin` not `<npm_glob_path>/node_modules/app-name/bin`. The `package.json` of your app is inside `<npm_glob_path>/node_modules/app-name`. And don't use `./`, always use `path` calls

Hence try this instead (replace `app-name` by your app's name):

```js
import { dirname } from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

const __dirname = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url))
console.log('__dirname:' + __dirname) // TELL ME WHAT YOU SEE HERE WHEN YOU RUN THE CLI CMD

const packageJsonLocation = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'app-name' 'package.json')
const packageJson = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(
  path.join(__dirname, 'package.json'), 'utf8')
)
```

And please, add `console.log('__dirname:' + __dirname)` after defining `__dirname`. Which path do you see when you run the CLI app?

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work with es modules.

Comment: I tried this, but I get the same issue with other folders https://flaviocopes.com/fix-dirname-not-defined-es-module-scope/

Comment: @iosifv what do you mean by "the same issue with other folders"? Be sure the script where your code is (code above), is located in the same directory of `package.json`

Comment: add `console.log(__dirname)` after defining `__dirname`. When you run the code, what do you see?

Comment: By other folders I mean: This is a CLI app, so when I install it and get it's executable I  expect it to work from anywhere. Imagine having the executable "ls" which works only in /usr/bin/

Comment: I did try your edited solution and by using an import still doesn't work. I will update my original question so that it's much clearer

Comment: @iosifv I understood is a CLI app and basically you're referring to the working directory. But add `console.log(__dirname)` after the definition of `__dirname`?

Comment: @iosifv check my edit and tell me if it works

Comment: OMG, 10 npm publishes later, it's working. Your provided example was ok in the end with a small tweak. Here's where I used it https://github.com/iosifv/cli-path/blob/main/cli-app/bin/clip.js#L33 lines about 33 to 59 (if I don't make any more commits in the meantime)

Answer (score 1):

> is there a better way for approaching this?

Yes - you should store the version number in the actual package itself somewhere. This way it will always be available/accessible and there's no risk of the package.json version and the installed version becoming out of sync. For example, if someone adds your package to a project and then runs `yarn install`, but later uses `git pull` to get an up-to-date version of their local files which happens to include a version bump for your package, there is a window where the package.json has a different version number to the installed version.